# How did Stack Overflow decide on point structure?

Tags: discussion, reputation

How were point values decided and is there any research on the topic? Point aggregate systems seem like an interesting topic. How do you calculate a number that is supposed to represent your level or responsibility and knowledge?

The other interesting side of the coin is that points can systematically affect behavior (especially if you consider not only points but tags).

Comment: The oldest [What is reputation How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) on [the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130609062938/http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is from 2013, and the points numbers seem at a glance unchanged since then. Maybe you can find earlier references on it that contain different numbers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "point values" exactly? It's an arbitrary system and there is no "value" as such, no?. If you mean the decision how many points an upvote gives, how many points a downvote takes, etc., I'm fairly sure that was largely a gut decision on the part of the founders, Jeff and Joel. If you want to learn more about the background, the very early podcasts are very helpful

Comment: Yes, I meant the points added to reputation. Half of my question was about how much thought was put into it. In which case, the podcasts sound interesting. Stackoverflow seems to be ever-evolving so I'm also curious if there have been studies on the effect that point shifts would have on the system. Arbitrary or not, points determine privileges which are a very tangible result from reputation. An interesting discussion indeed.

Comment: Downvotes on questions also used to cost rep. But the crap questions started piling up, they would get upvoted for various ridiculous reasons, and no one wanted to downvote them because it cost rep.

Comment: @yellowantphil: that's a great find! "This is a public beta", we can't (legally ;) go much further back than that. There should be some reasoning or justification, then, to change the upvote rep later on. But I guess that's for the OP to locate that point in time, and correlate with votes before and after ...

Comment: Blog about the change from +10 to +5 for question upvotes: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/